# A problem of weak convergence of stochastic processes

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes, convergence, characteristic-function

Let $(X_1,X_2, ....)$ be a infinite sequence of random variables. Supoose that te sequence is strictly stationary. For all $n$, define the following infinite array:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  Y_1 & Y_2 & \cdots & Y_n \\
  Y_{n+1} & Y_{n+2} & \cdots & Y_{2n} \\
  Y_{2n+1} & Y_{2n+2} & \cdots & Y_{3n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
  Y_{kn+1} & Y_{kn+2} & \cdots & Y_{kn} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Such that the first row is $(Y_1,Y_2, \cdots, Y_n )=(X_1,X_2, \cdots, X_n )$ and the other rows are independent copies of the first one, i.e., the sequence $(V^k)_{k\geq 2}$, $V^{k}:=(Y_{kn+1}, Y_{kn+2}, \cdots, Y_{kn})$, are iid according to $(X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n)$.

Finally, let $v$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,…,n\}$. Define $(Z_t)_{t \geq 1}$ as:
$$Z_{t}:= Y_{t+v}, \quad (t \geq 1)$$
To make the notation lighter, we will not use the index $n$ in the sequence $(Z_t)_{t \geq 1}$. But it's good to remember that the construction of $(Z_t)_{t \geq 1}$ depends on $n$.

I want to show that $(Z_t)_{t \geq 1}$ converges in the weak topology, i.e., the convergence of finite-dimensional distributions, to $(X_t)_{t \geq 1}$, as $n$ tends to infinity.

**My attempt**

*(Initially, I was considering a draw of $v$ for every $t$, but a comment alerted me to this error. So, what follows is already corrected version of my attempt)*

I will try to show that $(Z_{t_1}, Z_{t_2}) \implies (X_{t_1}, X_{t_2})$, as $n \to \infty$, for fixed $(t_1, t_2)$

*(Actually, I would have to show for any $(t_1,...,t_p) \in \mathbb Z^p$, but for simplicity let's assume $p=2$. Furthermore, assume without loss of generality that $t_1< t_2$)*.

For this, I will use the method of characteristic functions.  Note that for $n$ large enough, we have that $t_1 < t_2 < n$. So:
$$(Z_{t_1}, Z_{t_2})= (Y_{t_1 + v}, Y_{t_2 + v})= (X_{n\kappa_1 + r_1}, X_{n\kappa_2 + r_2}):=W, \quad \kappa_i = 0,1; \,\, 1\leq r_i<n, \, i=1,2$$
Note that if $\kappa_i = 0$, we have $r_i = t_i$. Moreover, I think that:
$$\mathbb P(\kappa_i = 0)=1- t_i/n\quad \mathbb P(\kappa_i = 1)=t_i/n$$

So, for $u=(u_1,u_2)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_W(u)&= \mathbb E \left[ e^{ i u 'W }  \right] = \mathbb E \left[ e^{ i (u_1 X_{n\kappa_1+r_1} + u_2 Y_{n\kappa_2+r_2} )}  \right]\\
&= \mathbb E \left[ e^{ i (u_1 X_{t_1} + u_2 X_{t_2} )}  \right]\mathbb P[\kappa_1 = 0,\kappa_2 = 0] \\
&+ \mathbb E \left[ e^{ i (u_1 X_{t_1} + u_2 X_{n+r_2} )}  \right] \mathbb P[\kappa_1 = 0,\kappa_2 = 1] \\
&+ \mathbb E \left[ e^{ i (u_1 X_{n+r_1} + u_2 Y_{n+r_2} )}  \right]\mathbb P[\kappa_1 = 1,\kappa_2 = 1]
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_W(u)=& \varphi_{(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2})}(u) (1- t_1/n)(1- t_2/n)\,\,\,\,+\\
&\mathbb E \left[ e^{ i (u_1 X_{t_1} + u_2 X_{n+r_2} )}  \right] (1- t_1/n) t_2/n \,\,\,\,+\\
& \mathbb E \left[ e^{ i (u_1 X_{n+r_1} + u_2 Y_{n+r_2} )}  \right]t_1/n\,\,t_2/n
\end{aligned}
$$
This shows that:
$$(Z_{t_1}, Z_{t_2})= (X_{t_1}, X_{t_2})+o_p(1)$$

Comment: Why do you use two different index shifts $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ in $(Z_{t_1},Z_{t_2})=(Y_{t_1+\nu_1},Y_{t_2+\nu_2})$? As far as I understand your definition of $(Z_t)$, it is a randomly index shifted copy of $(Y_t)$, or isn't it? If it were not, then the whole dependence structure would be messed up...

Comment: I think you are right. The original question is a problem of Durret's book:  > Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a stationary sequence. Let $n<\infty$ and let $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be a sequence so that $\left(Y_{n k+1}, \ldots, Y_{n(k+1)}\right), k \geq 0$ are i.i.d. and $\left(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n\right)=\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right)$. Finally, let $v$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$, independent of $Y$, and let $Z_m=Y_{v+m}$ for $m \geq 1$. Show that $Z$ is stationary and ergodic. I my case, I am interested on the convergence.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So you extended the original question where $n$ was still fixed :-) Another problem is, that you want to show convergence for all fidis, not only for the joint distribution of two $Z_{t_1}, Z_{t_2}$. You are argumenting "for $n$ large enough" that $(Z_{t_1},Z_{t_2}) \sim (X_{t_1+v},X_{t_2+v} )$. This is intuitively also, what I would go for. But since $v$ can take all values between $1$ and $n$, you would need to treat the still possible " too large" values of $v$ with caution.

Comment: Dear Ute, thank you very much for the suggestions. Would you be so kind as to check out my new attempt? Did I miss something?

Comment: The way you handle these cases that include a "jump" between two independent copies is also what I would do :-) I think something got a bit messed up with X and Y in between. (Y_t1+v, Y_t2+v)=(X_..,X_..) is not correct, you would need to divide this equation up in cases.Your last equation looks a bit strange to me. Btw, do you prefer guidance to get to your own solution, or would you rather like someone coming up with a proof? In the first case, you can set the self-study tag - some people respect this and would not post complete answers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At this stage of the game, I would prefer a formal proof of the problem!

Comment: I am wondering if you need a further condition for $(X_1,X_2,...)$ , something like mixing or ergodicity.

Comment: Certainly not. The idea of the problem is that it is possible to approximate (in weak topology) a strictly stationary process by a sequence of ergodic processes. The statement above is Exercise 1.9 (Chapter 6) of Durret's book, first edition. On the other hand, Exercise 2.10, from the same edition and chapter 6, asks to use Exercise 1.9 to show the density of ergodic processes.